Program Error: "Instruction #3 Failed - Account is frozen"
An error occurred when I purchased the IQ50 from birdeye. I tried several times but it still didn’t work.

The token was most likely frozen by the owner and you can no longer make transfers or perform any other operation with the token.
There is nothing you as the holder can do and you'd have to reach out to the creator/authority to revoke the permissions(freeze) on the token.
